# Cakephp with jquery multiple file uploader any example

Tags: jquery, cakephp, cakephp-1.3

Cakephp with jquery multiple file uploader any example ?

I need Jquery uploader to upload multiple files that can easily integrated with cakephp.
I tried few things but nothing works.

Comment: are you looking for a non-flash solution? i would be interested in that, too.

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried? Try uploading some code to http://bin.cakephp.org/ and posting the link here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way I can think of doing this, is to have

```
echo $this->Form->input('Upload.0.name', array('type' => 'file'));
echo $this->Form->button('Add another', array('type' => 'button', 'title' => 'Add another file upload'));
```

on page load.

Then you can bind jQuery code to the button that duplicates the last file input (div and all) and append it to the current list. The jQuery code can then count how many inputs have been created and replace the "0" with that number.

This explanation is a bit off-the-cuff, so let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: Can you explain more detail please ?

Comment: @Cakephp.Saint: What exactly do you need more detail on? What have you tried and what was the results?

Show some code examples and we can try and point you in the right direction.